# Capitalize string elements inside arrays that are inside an object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
let result = {
'i was sent': ["I was sent", "you were Awesome!"],
'to earth': ["to Earth" , "To moon"],
'to protect you': ["to protect you"]
}
```

What if we want to capitalize each first letter of all elements of the arrays and return the `result` like :

```
 let result = {
    'i was sent you to': ["I was sent", "You were Awesome!"],
    'to earth': ["To Earth" , "To moon"],
    'to protect you': ["To protect you"],
 }
```

I have tried this with no success (**Note that capitalize function works fine for strings**):

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {

     result[key].forEach(function(e) {
     capitalize(result[key][e]);
     });
});

console.log(result)

function capitalize(s) {
    let first_char = /\S/;
    return s.replace(first_char, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
 });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`capitalize()` doesn't modify the string in place, you need to use the returned value. You can use `.map()` to create an array of results and assign this back to the object element.

```js
let result = {
  'i was sent': ["I was sent", "you were Awesome!"],
  'to earth': ["to Earth", "To moon"],
  'to protect you': ["to protect you"]
}

Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
  result[key] = result[key].map(capitalize);
});

console.log(result)

function capitalize(s) {
  let first_char = /\S/;
  return s.replace(first_char, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand `map(capitalize)` how did you initiate the function, Where are the `()`? How did you pass the elements to the function

Comment: If you use `array.map(e => capitalize(e))` you've introduced an arrow function that takes one argument and passes that argument directly to `capitalize`. But this is an extra layer of unnecessary indirection since `capitalize` itself accepts one argument--we can skip the wrapper and pass the `capitalize` function directly as the callback to `map`.

Comment: @SaraRee `map()` calls the function on each element of the array, that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this in-place, a reassignment needs to happen to replace the original values. You can loop over the entries in the object with `for ... in` and assign the result of `map` to the object key.

```js
const data = {
  'i was sent': ["I was sent", "you were Awesome!"],
  'to earth': ["to Earth" , "To moon"],
  'to protect you': ["to protect you"]
};

for (const k in data) {
  data[k] = data[k].map(e => e.replace(/\S/, m => m.toUpperCase()));
}

console.log(data);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original, you can use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const data = {
  'i was sent': ["I was sent", "you were Awesome!"],
  'to earth': ["to Earth" , "To moon"],
  'to protect you': ["to protect you"]
};

const capitalize = s => s.replace(/\S/, m => m.toUpperCase());
const capitalizedData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) =>
  [k, v.map(capitalize)]
));

console.log(capitalizedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are not *reassigning* the values to the properties in the `result` object. Use the `map` method of the arrays to create a new array with capitalized strings and reassign it to the keys in the object.

```js
function capitalize(s) {
  let first_char = /\S/;
  return s.replace(first_char, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
}

let result = {
  'i was sent': ["I was sent", "you were Awesome!"],
  'to earth': ["to Earth" , "To moon"],
  'to protect you': ["to protect you"]
};

for (const [ key, value ] of Object.entries(result)) {
  result[key] = value.map(capitalize);
}

console.log(result);
```